# DM Script to import a 2D image in text (CSV) format

Tags: import-from-csv, dm-script

Using the built-in "Import Data..." functionality we can import a properly formatted text file (like CSV and/or tab-delimited) as an image. It is rather straight forward to write a script to do so. However, my scripting approach is not efficient - which requires me to loop through each raw (use the "StreamReadTextLine" function) so it takes a while to get a 512x512 image imported.

Is there a better way or an "undocumented" script function that I can tap in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DigitalMicrograph offers an import functionality via the `File/Import Data...` menu entry, which will give you this dialog:

[image: Import Image]

The functionality evoked by this dialog can also be accessed by script commands, with the command

`BasicImage ImageImportTextData( String img_name, ScriptObject stream, Number data_type_enum, ScriptObject img_size, Boolean lines_are_rows, Boolean size_by_counting )`

As with the dialog, one has to pre-specify a few things.

**The *data type* of the image.**

This is a number. You can find out which number belongs to which image data type by, f.e., creating an image outputting its data type:

```
image img := Realimage( "", 4, 100 )
Result("\n" + img.ImageGetDataType() )
```

**The file stream object**

This object describes where the data is stored. The F1 help-documention explains how one creates a file-stream from an existing file, but essentially you need to specify a path to the file, then open the file for reading (which gives you a handle), and then using the fileHandle to create the stream object.

```
string path = "C:\\test.txt"
number fRef = OpenFileForReading( path )
object fStream = NewStreamFromFileReference( fRef, 1 )
```

**The image size object**

This is a specific *script object* you need to allocate. It wraps image size information. In case of auto-detecting the size from the text, you don't need to specify the actual size, but you still need the object.

```
object imgSizeObj = Alloc("ImageData_ImageDataSize")
imgSizeObj.SetNumDimensions(2)      // Not needed for counting!
imgSizeObj.SetDimensionSize(0,10)   // Not used for counting
imgSizeObj.SetDimensionSize(1,10)   // Not used for counting
```

**Boolean checks**

Like with the checkboxes in the UI, you spefic two conditions:

- Lines are Rows
- Get Size By Counting

Note, that the "counting" flag is only used if "Lines are Rows" is also true. Same as with the dialog.
[image]

---

The following script improrts a text file with couting:

```
image ImportTextByCounting( string path, number DataType )
{

    number fRef     = OpenFileForReading( path )
    object fStream  = NewStreamFromFileReference( fRef, 1 )
    number bLinesAreRows    = 1
    number bSizeByCount     = 1 
    bSizeByCount *= bLinesAreRows // Only valid together!

    object imgSizeObj = Alloc("ImageData_ImageDataSize")

    image img := ImageImportTextData( "Imag Name ", fStream, DataType, imgSizeObj, bLinesAreRows, bSizeByCount )
    return img
}

string path = "C:\\test.txt"
number kREAL4_DATA      = 2
image img := ImportTextByCounting( path, kREAL4_DATA )
img.ShowImage()
```

Comment: As a remark: the "binary" import part of the dialog can also be accessed via a script command, but here there is virtually no speed improvement over just binary-streaming things in as described in the F1 help documentation. So I have not described this here - it was also not asked for. The speed improvement for *text* import comes of course from the fact, that no (scripted) for-loop is required.