# Import Raw DM Command

Tags: dm-script

Is there a command in Digital Micrograph that allows you to import a binary 3D dataset? The goal is to reproduce what File->Import->Import Image does, but in a script.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. The command is

> `BasicImage ImageImportBinaryData( String img_name, ScriptObject stream, Number data_type_enum, ScriptObject img_size, Number offset, Boolean swap )`

It maps onto the exact UI functionality of the "File/Import Data" menu command.

See also this answer here on [text import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48962283/1302888) for further details.

---

But you may alternatively use the binary streaming described in the F1 help documentation in more detail here, which can give you more control:

[image: Raw streaming help]